# Why is nav not aligning in the center of the header?

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9418g1z6/)

HTML:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main_nav {
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    padding-top: 35px;
}
```

Why is the `nav` not aligning in the center of the `header`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give unwanted `margin` of `padding` to adjust your html

Here is a working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9418g1z6/6/)

removed `padding-top` `margin` etc and **added:**

```
header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: scroll;
  justify-content: center;
}
header h1{
  min-width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}
#search_and_avatar{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

header {
 background-color:#151515;
 overflow:hidden;
 height: 100px;
}

h1 {
 color:#FFF;
 font-family: "Arial Rounded MT", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height:25px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
}

header h1, img, #search_form {
 float:left;
}

#main_nav a {
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#main_nav {
 display: table;
 text-align:center;
 width:50%;
}

#main_nav ul {
 display: table-row;
}

#main_nav ul li {
 padding: 15px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 top: 50%;
 display:inline;
}

header img {
 width:35px;
}

header{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 overflow: scroll;
 justify-content: center;
}
header h1{
 flex: 1;
 min-width: 250px;
 margin: 0;
}
header form{
 text-align: right;
}

#search_and_avatar{
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>CSS-Tricks</h1>
            <nav id="main_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="video_screencasts.html">Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="almanac.html">Almanac</a></li>
                    <li><a href="snippets.html">Snippets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lodge.html">Lodge</a></li>
                    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
            <div id="search_and_avatar">
            <form action="index.html" method="post" id="search_form">
              <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
            </form>
            <img src="images/avatar.png">
            </div>
            <!--
            <ul id="account_nav">
                <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
            -->
        </header>
 </div>
```

Comment: Its not perfectly centered though.

Comment: @Grey-lover Updated. Unfortunately there was some `padding-top` for `h1`

Comment: It is even more right than center now. I am viewing in Chrome by the way.

Comment: Ohh you mean vertical center or horizontal center?

Comment: I mean horizontal center, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122163/discussion-between-grey-lover-and-syam-pillai).

Answer (score 2):

```
#main_nav {
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, after applying that change, it is a little bit more on the right now then center, you can check the updated fiddle. Do you know why?

Comment: UL elements by default have a boat load of padding, are you removing it?

Comment: @jedifans i tried removing the default padding of ul. Its still not perfectly centered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: table;` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `nav`

```
#main_nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Check this [**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9418g1z6/1/)

Comment: Hi in your fiddle its not perfectly in center of the header

Comment: remove display: table-row; in your ul

Comment: That did not help, I am afraid.